# Samsung Galaxy S3 “Not registered on network”

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, custom-roms, sim-card, mobile-network, cellular-radio

It had stock 4.0.4 -> could call.

I've flashed FoxHound ROM -> after a while, when I try calling, it says "Not registered on network" .

Tried GalaxSim, but everything looks ok.

Restored back to stock and tried another SIM -> same error.

Do you have any clue? I cannot make any phone calls, nor access the internet.

Comment: if you press *#06# on the dialer do you get your imei number?

Comment: @Schutzstaffel have you got the solution to your problem, I face the same on my samsung galaxy chat. It used to work even after official upgrade, but suddenly stopped working and gives me the same error as in your case.